# Why is the mail() function sending an email with body "0"?

Tags: ajax, php

This is being sent via Ajax. Here's the JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: objCommon.ajax,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {type:'feedback', msg:$('.commonsFeedbackDiv').text(), url:window.location.href},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if(data.search('ajaxError') === -1){
            console.log('sent');
        }else if(data.search('msg')){
            alert('Please enter a message.');
        }
    }
});
```

And the PHP that processes the request:

```
global $user;
echo $_POST['msg'];
echo $_POST['url'];
if(isset($_POST['msg']) && $_POST['msg'] !== ''){
    mail('commons@example.com', 'Commons Feedback', 'url: ' + $_POST['url'] + $_POST['msg'], 'From: ' . $user->mail);
}else{
    echo 'ajaxError - no msg';
}
```

You can see in the `success()` callback function that I'm logging the response to the console, and this response is made up of the two `echo` statements near the beginning of the PHP code. The string that ends up in the console is correct; it contains both the message and the URL. However, the actual email I receive simply contains the number 0 in the content.

Any idea why?

Comment: And don't forget to *sanitize* your input!
http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: I am -- just removed it for the sake of this post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operator to concatenate strings in php is `.` not `+`. The plus sign performs numerical addition, which in turn converts strings into the value 0.

Therefore you need to change

```
'url: ' + $_POST['url'] + $_POST['msg']
```

to

```
'url: ' . $_POST['url'] . $_POST['msg']
```

Comment: Good find, +1 for this answer.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it would be something small like that. Mixing up my JS & PHP :)